# setInterval or setTimeout with String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Now I test the following codes about `setInterval` and `setTimeout` with `String` as parameter.

```
>> setInterval(String,2) 
2214 
>> setInterval(String,2) 
2215
```

In IE, the output is `2214`, I want to know why the result is `2214`?

But test it in Chrome, the output is

```
setInterval(String, 2)
18
setInterval(String, 2)
19
```

According to the syntax of setInterval:

```
setInterval(func|code, delay)
```

So I try the following

```
>> String 
 function String() {     [native code] } 
>> String() 
""
```

There is no actual number result.

Also I try it with `setTimeout`

```
setInterval(String, 2)
20
setInterval(String, 2)
21
setTimeout(String, 2)
22
```

I am not clear what happened about those codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` return timer IDs. These help the browser recognize them again if you clear them, but you don't need to worry about their specific values.

The function/code that is run has nothing to do with the return value of `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()`. The return value of the code, AFAIK, will be thrown away unless you put it somewhere. As Thilo said in the comments, the code will not even have been run by the time `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()` returns.

Comment: in particular, they are completely unrelated to whatever the called function returns (which will not even have been invoked yet).